# What is the equivalent of @DataJpaTest if I just want to test JdbcTemplate code?

Tags: java, testing, spring-boot

Spring Boot 1.4 offers some fantastic testing improvements. One is the `@DataJpaTest` annotation where it wires up just the parts needed for JPA testing. What would the equivalent look like for just wiring up the parts needed for `JdbcTemplate` tests?

I'm fine constructing my own composite annotation that mimics the `@DataJpaTest` one.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Good question. Ironically enough, that one was raised during the testing talk yesterday at SpringOne Platform. Let's see what it takes to implement such dedicated test annotation.

`TL;DR` [check the code on github](https://github.com/snicoll-scratches/demo-data-jdbc-test)

First of all you need to create the annotation. This annotation reuses some bits from the `spring-boot-test-autoconfigure` module. You may want to auto-configure an in-memory database (like `DataJpaTest` does). You also want to make sure that caching is configured and disabled by default (in case you have `@EnableCaching` on your Spring Boot application). You also want that all your tests are `@Transactional` by default so you should add that.

Next, you want that slicing effectively kicks in. All you need at this point is a `DataSource`, a `JdbcTemplate`, database migrations (flyway/liquibase) and a transaction manager to process `@Transactional`. To avoid the other auto-configurations to kick in you should add the following:

```
@OverrideAutoConfiguration(enabled = false)
```

Then, you want to explicitly enable the auto-configurations above. In order to do so, you add `@ImportAutoConfiguration` and you add the following content in `META-INF/spring.factories`

```
# AutoConfigureDataJpa auto-configuration imports
com.example.test.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataJdbcTest=\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.flyway.FlywayAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration,\      
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration,\    
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.JdbcTemplateAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.liquibase.LiquibaseAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.transaction.TransactionAutoConfiguration
```

The key in `spring.factories` should match the FQN of your annotation. Whenever Spring Boot finds `@ImportAutoConfiguration` with no extra attributes, it will look for a key matching the annotation type in `spring.factories`.

Next up you want to be able to include additional components (component scan) with a filter. In order to do that, you can add `@TypeExcludeFilters(DataJdbcTypeExcludeFilter.class)` where `DataJdbcTypeExcludeFilter` is pretty much the same thing as `DataJpaTypeExcludeFilter` (so we might want to extract a common class for that).

Once you've done that, you only need to add your annotation and your `JdbcTemplate` is auto-configured for you

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@DataJdbcTest
public class DataJdbcSampleTests {

    @Autowired
    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the excellent answer! Also, I'm the fellow that raised the question in the session ;)

Comment: That's awesome! I am glad it helps.

Comment: the solution is fantastic, however I ran into a bug in `TestDatabaseAutoConfiguration` where it is trying to log out the `DataSource` by `logger.info("Replacing \'" + holder.getBeanName() + "\' DataSource bean with embedded version");` but is instead getting a `NullPointerException`

Comment: NPE on a typo seems harsh. Can you please report what you had and the exception in our tracker? We'll hava a look to improve the error message.

Answer (score 0):

I think the option will be [@JdbcTest](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-testing.html#boot-features-testing-spring-boot-applications-testing-autoconfigured-jdbc-test), you could found further info on doc.