# JdbcTemplate not configured when using @DataJpaTest

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, spring-boot, jdbctemplate

I created a test with @DataJpaTest annotation. hsqldb is configured but I'm getting error:

```
No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate]
```

In the project I'm using JPA repositories and JdbcTemplates. It is working fine when I'm using real Oracle DB configuration. Why JdbcTemplate is not configured automatically ? What should I do in order to fix this problem ?

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = {MyApplication.class})
@DataJpaTest
public class IntegrationTest
```

Dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.el</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.el-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.4</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
    <optional>true</optional>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>args4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>args4j</artifactId>
    <version>2.33</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-remote-shell</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
    <version>2.6</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>oracle</groupId>
    <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
    <version>11.2.0.3.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.netflix.hystrix</groupId>
    <artifactId>hystrix-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.18</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.perf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>perf4j</artifactId>
    <version>0.9.16</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.reactivex</groupId>
    <artifactId>rxjava</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.13</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.3.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Properties:

```
spring.jpa.database=ORACLE
spring.jpa.show-sql=false
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=validate

spring.datasource.driverClassName=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
spring.datasource.url=..
spring.datasource.username=..
spring.datasource.password=..

spring.datasource.max-active=20
spring.datasource.max-idle=5
spring.datasource.min-idle=1
spring.datasource.initial-size=5


spring.datasource.testWhileIdle = true
spring.datasource.timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis = 20000
#spring.datasource.test-on-borrow=true
spring.datasource.validation-query=select 1 from dual;

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.order_inserts=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.order_updates=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.batch_size=100
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache=false
```

Comment: Property file contains oracle. Can you paste the configurations?

Comment: Properties that I included are used in standard mode. I don't have anly other properties. I'm assuming that annotation @DataJpaTest is handling configuration of in memory DB. For now I only overwritten one property for testing: spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none

Comment: Hmmm. Can you please show the complete error log?

Answer (score 3):

It's not configured at the moment. I've [already answered how to create your own slice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38746788/what-is-the-equivalent-of-datajpatest-if-i-just-want-to-test-jdbctemplate-code/38748057#38748057) and I've recently wrote [a blog post about it](https://spring.io/blog/2016/08/30/custom-test-slice-with-spring-boot-1-4).

There is no particular reason why `JdbcTemplate` isn't configured with `DataJpaTest`. The main use case for that annotation is to test your *JPA* data layer. When you do, you're probably not supposed to use a `JdbcTemplate` but I understand you may like that in your test to alter the database or something?

I've created [#6802](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/6802) to track your request, please follow there for updates.

Comment: There is another use case: test a DAO class which uses JdbcTemplate. That's not a JPA test, but in-memory database autoconfiguration is quite usefull for a JdbcTemplate DAO test too.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to resolve my problem by simply adding this file into the test scoped package

```
@Configuration
public class TestConfig {
    @Bean
    public JdbcTemplate getJdbcTemplate(DataSource dataSource) {
        return new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    }
}
```