# @DataJpaTest equivalent for elasticsearch

Tags: java, spring, elasticsearch, spring-boot

In Spring Boot we can test the the Spring Data JPA slice of an application by annotating the test case with `@DataJpaTest`.

Is there an equivalent for testing an elasticsearch slice?

`@DataJpaTest` looks like this. Maybe it is possible to create an `@DataElasticsearchTest` annotation?

```
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Documented
@Inherited
@BootstrapWith(SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper.class)
@OverrideAutoConfiguration(enabled = false)
@TypeExcludeFilters(DataJpaTypeExcludeFilter.class)
@Transactional
@AutoConfigureCache
@AutoConfigureDataJpa
@AutoConfigureTestDatabase
@AutoConfigureTestEntityManager
@ImportAutoConfiguration
public @interface DataJpaTest {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Does [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38746788/what-is-the-equivalent-of-datajpatest-if-i-just-want-to-test-jdbctemplate-code/38748057#38748057) helps?

Comment: I think it does. Thanks!