# Minimizing classes to load for JUnit testing

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Let's say I'm testing a repository :

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class UserRepositoryTest {
  @Test
  (...)
  @Test
  (...)
}
```

I'm ok that spring loads other repositories, but I'm not ok it loads the embedded Tomcat, the services, the controllers, ... every time I launch one of these JUnit.

What is the simplest way to achieve this?

I've tried to put some inner `@Configuration` class with a `@ComponentScan` limited to my repository package but it didn't work (it was just ignored).

Comment: Just specify within the `classes` argument fo the `@SpringBootTest` annotation which classes it should use. This can either be a local Spring configuration, some `AutoConfiguration` you want to load or some service/component specified classes.

Comment: Well, I have some "configuration" classes for very specific things (security, database, swagger, ...) but I don't have config classes to group my beans, they are all scanned. And I don't have a config which tells Tomcat to start. What should I disable before going your way ?

Comment: By default `@SpringBootTest` will not perform a `@ComponentScan` AFAIK. If no nested `@Configuration` class is available it will search its tree upwards for any and use this instead. You can, of course, always define some nested ones along the line `@Configuration static class Config { @Bean CustomService customService() { return mock(CustomService.class); } }` within your test class or try to [exclude classes from being component scanned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18992880/exclude-component-from-componentscan)

Comment: If you create a configuration in a test class itself, you should use `@TestConfiguration` annotation instead of `@Configuration`

Comment: `@TestConfiguration` is for additional config, @Configuration is to replace config, which is what I want.

Answer (score 4):

Use the annotation `@DataJpaTest` instead of `@SpringBootTest`. It only loads the persistence related part of Spring.

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@DataJpaTest
public class UserRepositoryTest {
  @Test
  (...)
  @Test
  (...)
}
```

You will find a detailed solution [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-testing.html#boot-features-testing-spring-boot-applications-testing-autoconfigured-jpa-test)

If you have some usage of `JdbcTemplate` then take a look to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38746788/what-is-the-equivalent-of-datajpatest-if-i-just-want-to-test-jdbctemplate-code/38748057#38748057)

Comment: It's good to know. But not really an answer for all case. Right now, I'm using spring-jdbc. Also I may have some test with only 1 service dependency.

Comment: Maybe it is better to clarify in the question that you are using `JdbcTemplate`.

Comment: But the question is not especially about the repository layer, this is just an example. Also, I've found "@JdbdTest", but it's still a very partial answer.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like there is not one single answer to this question.

Of course, for JPA repositories, Lore answer is the best : use @DataJpaTest (or @JdbcTest for my use case). But be also sure to use "`@AutoConfigureTestDatabase(replace = Replace.NONE)`" if your test data is in your database and not in some in-memory one.

Also there is a special chapter talking about this in Spring doc :

> Spring Boot’s auto-configuration system works well for applications
>   but can sometimes be a little too much for tests. It often helps to
>   load only the parts of the configuration that are required to test a
>   “slice” of your application.

source : https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-testing.html#boot-features-testing-spring-boot-applications-testing-autoconfigured-tests

But it doesn't show all you can/need to do.

For example, I had a smtpClientService to test.

To test this service, alone in its own layer, I had to do these specific adaptations (if I omit "@AutoConfigureWebClient", I won't get RestTemplateBuilder injected) :

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureWebClient
public class smtpClientServiceTest {

  @Autowired
  SmtpClientService service;

  @Configuration
  @Import(SmtpClientConfig.class)
  @ComponentScan(basePackageClasses = SmtpClientService.class)
  static class TestConfiguration {
  }  

  @Test
  public void testSendMessage() {
    (...)
  }

}
```